# node_modules minified codes and Electron-packager

Tags: electron, minify, node-modules, electron-packager

I can see in `my myproject\node_modules` modules(not all) which get normal `.js` code and `.min.js` versions:
For example `jsonpath` 
After running the packager I get the same two files in the `myproject-win32-ia32\node_modules\jsonpath` folder.
So my question is: Is there anyway of saying to the packager (or other utility I could run before packaging)to keep only the minified (or the original) if both exist

I find not so good to keep both versions, the installed package at the end is bigger than it should be for nothing....

Comment: This is somewhat hard to answer since it depends on your setup and separation of frontendcode/backend code. Usually Frontendcode is bundled and allready minified it should __not__ end up in node_modules. But Backend code does and it is also probably not always minified. Could you give a little more insight into your projects structure ?

Comment: I've never spoken of frontend and backend, I'm only speaking of the content of the folder node_modules in the packaged output.There is nothing to do with my project structure...